# VB .NET copy a webpage content and paste to new outlook reply

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm trying to copy a website body content in VB .NET (text, image, hyperlink, etc) and paste it into a new email in outlook (everything automated).

The issue I've come to is that I can copy the innerhtml but that will be an HTML code and when it paste it to the outlook you can see the  tags etc.

The innertext only copies the text so no hyperlink, no text formatting and no images.

What I'm trying to do is like when you do CTRL+A on a page and go to outlook and select paste (keep source formatting).

I haven't found any solutions how I can implement that...

```
Dim objIE = New InternetExplorer
With objIE
  .Top = 0
  .Left = 0
  .Width = 800
  .Height = 800
  .Visible = visible
  .Navigate(url)
End With
Dim content = objIE.Document.Body.InnerHTML
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution :)

```
Dim ol As Object 'Outlook.Application
        Dim olEmail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
        Dim signature As String 'string

        '/* if outlook is running use GO, create otherwise */
        ol = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
        olEmail = ol.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

        With olEmail
            .Display
        End With
        signature = olEmail.HTMLBody
        With olEmail
            .To = ""
            '/* bonus basic html */
            .HTMLBody = signature & objIE.Document.all.item(0).outerhtml
            .Display
        End With
```